# What do I use for my URL in postman?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, postman

I'm new to restful apis, trying to learn them. I have created a mongo database and am using it in cloud9. My get request works:

```
app.get('/api/movies/:moviename', function(request, response) {
  movies.find({Title: "avatar"}, {Title: 1, _id: 0}).toArray(function(err, results) { 
    // in here you have a results variable [array] with your results
    response.write(JSON.stringify({data: results}));
    response.end();
  }); // ends students find toArray
}); // end app get handler
```

But my post is not working. I am using postman and entering the following:
[image: postmandcapture]
Here is my server code for the post request:

```
app.post('api/movies/:moviename', function(request, response) {
  var movieName = request.params.moviename;
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": "application/json"});
  var insData = request.body;
  movies.insert(insData).toArray(function (err, result) {
    if(!err){
      response.write(JSON.stringify(insData));
    }else{
      response.write("no data");
    }
    response.end();
  });
});
```

I am just trying to add another movie as a json object to my mongo database. I thought maybe the url that I used in postman was the problem. When I submit in postman it just says cannot post /api/movies/junglebook Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't written the code to write your post data to MongoDB e.g. `movies.insert(insData, function (err, result) { ... });`

Comment: Can you share the POST request and response headers?

Comment: @chridam I just updated my code with an insert, but I still get the same thing in postman..

Comment: You missed a `/` in front of your `app.post` route.

Comment: You don't need the request parameter for the post since you are inserting data (unless if you want to do an implicit update, which can be done with `app.put`). Try to change the API route to `app.post('api/movies/', function(request, response) { ... }` and in your post just do `http://yoururl/api/movies/` with your post data.

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you Blaze and chridam! This is what I used that worked for me:     app.post('/api/movies/:moviename', function(request, response) {
      var movieName = request.params.moviename;
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": "application/json"});
      var insData = request.body;
      response.write(JSON.stringify(insData));
      response.end();
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much Blaze! I didn't see that missing forward slash; and thank you as well chridam, it did work without the request parameter! I didn't need the movies.insert function after all, this worked for me and it is now in the database:

```
app.post('/api/movies/:moviename', function(request, response) {
  var movieName = request.params.moviename;
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": "application/json"});
  var insData = request.body;
  response.write(JSON.stringify(insData));
  response.end();
});
```